# Customize multiple labels or buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, label

In my objective-c code I customize different labels and UIButtons, but I don't know how to edit all them together, for example:

```
[[CincKmButton layer] setCornerRadius:10];
[CincKmButton setClipsToBounds:YES];
[[CincKmButton layer] setBorderColor:
 [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] CGColor]];
[CincKmButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pickerBackground.jpg"]]];
[[CincKmButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.75];

[[DeuKmButton layer] setCornerRadius:10];
[DeuKmButton setClipsToBounds:YES];
[[DeuKmButton layer] setBorderColor:
 [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] CGColor]];
[DeuKmButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pickerBackground.jpg"]]];
[[DeuKmButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.75];

[[HalfButton layer] setCornerRadius:10];
[HalfButton setClipsToBounds:YES];
[[HalfButton layer] setBorderColor:
 [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] CGColor]];
[HalfButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pickerBackground.jpg"]]];
[[HalfButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.75];
```

How can I do it without repating every time? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would likely be creating an `NSArray` of the buttons and a method to do the customization. It would end up looking something like

```
...
for (UIButton *button in @[CincKmButton,DeuKmButton,HalfButton]) {
    [self configureButton:button]
}
...

- (void) configureButton:(UIButton *)button {
    [button setClipsToBounds:YES];
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor;
    button.layer.borderWidth = 2.75;
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pickerBackground.jpg"]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a subclass of `UIButton` and write those properties in that class.

And use the Created Class instead of `UIButton`

or else

```
[[UIButton appearance] setClipsToBounds:YES];
[[UIButton appearance].layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
//similarly apply all properties to appearance class, this will automatically get applied to all UIButtons
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
CincKmButton.layer.cornerRadius = DeuKmButton.layer.cornerRadius  = 10;
CincKmButton.backgroundColor = DeuKmButton.backgroundColor  = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pickerBackground.jpg"]];
```

Or create a NSMutableArray of UIButton and edit all at the same time with a "for"

Or you can make an UIButton subclass to set all this properties with a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method and send the button to it.

```
-(void) assignButtonProperties :(UIButton *)sampleButton
{
   [[sampleButton layer] setCornerRadius:10];
   [sampleButton setClipsToBounds:YES];
   [[sampleButton layer] setBorderColor: [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] CGColor]];
   [sampleButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pickerBackground.jpg"]]];
   [[sampleButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.75];
}
```

for eg :

```
[self assignButtonProperties : CincKmButton];
[self assignButtonProperties : DeuKmButton];
```

Comment: you method name suggest that you assign the button to something, but you asking stuff to it.